# Is my firefox compromised?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

My Firefox version is 65.0.1 (64 bit) running on Ubuntu 18.04. I've installed extensions uBlock Origin v1.18.4, Gnome Shell Integration, and Video DownloadHelper 7.3.5. Only plugin is OpenH264 Video Codec provided by Cisco Systems, Inc. (installed by default).

Recently, Firefox began to display system notifications containing various advertisements. When I click on them, they usually open some add containing website that gets blocked by uBlock.

Following are some examples. These notifications are displayed even when the Firefox window is minimized.

[image: first one]

[image: second one]

What is happening? How do I stop this?

I've seen this kind of stuff on Windows, but surprised to see them on Ubuntu (that claims to be privacy oriented).

Thank you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This does not sound like your system has been compromised, rather you have push notifications enabled. Disable them in the browser. (See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/push-notifications-firefox )

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.